# Segmentation fault when installing ree-1.8.7-2011.03

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to install `ree-1.8.7-2011.03` using `rbenv install ree-1.8.7-2011.03`, but I get this error in the log files:

```
...
ar rcu libruby-static.a array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o dir.o dln.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o pointerset.o process.o prec.o random.o range.o re.o regex.o ruby.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o string.o struct.o time.o util.o variable.o version.o  dmyext.o
gcc -g -O2  -pipe -fno-common    -DRUBY_EXPORT  -I. -I. -I'/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -c main.c
gcc -g -O2  -pipe -fno-common    -DRUBY_EXPORT  -I. -I. -I'/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -c dmydln.c
gcc -g -O2  -pipe -fno-common    -DRUBY_EXPORT  -L. -L'/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib'    main.o dmydln.o libruby-static.a -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib -L/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib -lsystem_allocator -ldl -lobjc   -o miniruby
./ext/purelib.rb:2: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.8.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03

make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap
```

I've also tried downloading [the source](http://rubyenterpriseedition.googlecode.com/files/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03.tar.gz), and installing from there, but I get the same segmentation fault.

I'm on a mac using Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

Any ideas why?

Comment: What version of `gcc` are you using?

Comment: The version from `gcc --version` is `i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by doing `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rbenv install ree-1.8.7-2011.03`. I think the problem is that I have an old version of `ruby-build`.

Got the idea from http://www.andygoundry.com/2012/02/24/helping-out-rvm-on-mac/